# CORS - not enabling

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, environment-variables

- **SOLUTION:**

I had my port hardcoded... smh

```
app.listen(5432, () => { 
  console.log(`Server is listening on port 5432`) 
})
```

Heroku REQUIRES a `process.env.PORT`, this solved the issue here:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5432
app.listen(PORT, () => { 
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`) 
})
```

- **PROBLEM:**

I have a simple ReactJS CRUD form with no validation hosted locally, and a NodeJS Express server hosted on Heroku. Just trying to get cors enabled but nothing I do is setting the headers for the preflight request. Receiving this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://cors-be.herokuapp.com/api/user/create' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

This is the **index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.options("*", cors()) // Edit 1

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({message: "API is listening"})
})

const userRouter = require("./api/user/router")

app.use("/api/user", userRouter)

app.listen(5432, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port 5432`)
})
```

CORS version installed in **package.json**:

```
"cors": "^2.8.5"
```

This should be enabling all cors across all origins but it isn't. I've tested it on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge with the same result so I'm sure it's not a browser-specific issue. Everything functions correctly on localhost. It's a preflight request error so it wouldn't be an issue with my endpoint code anyway. Been working on this longer than I care to admit and I'm at the point where I will be happy just to get past the preflight request and add origin configuration later.

Edit 1:

Pre-flight seems to be looking for OPTIONS so I've added:

```
app.options("*", cors())
```

new **index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.options("*", cors())
```

but still isn't working...

Comment: It may not be getting the OPTIONS req. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: Ty, added `app.options("*", cors())`, still no luck

Comment: Can I see your app log? maybe it crashed

Comment: App Logs:

`2022-06-17T16:42:40.404637+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is listening on port 5432

2022-06-17T16:43:38.676472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

2022-06-17T16:43:38.928070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2022-06-17T16:43:39.106190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2022-06-17T16:43:39.158130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: What I get from this is that it is a MUST to have a process.env.PORT? Is that what is crashing my server? I'll add and test...

Comment: TYVM! It worked! I can't believe that was it, but that was it... TY TY TY! :D